# Delete old entry when same data entered elsewhere?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with 190 names and tables where the people sit.

I would like to automate the action of searching where a person has sat before and deleting the name on the old sitting place when I write in the same name on the new sitting place.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub One_Find()
    Dim Placeholder As Integer
    Dim FieldRange As Range
    Set FieldRange = Cells.Find(What:=ActiveCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, _
      LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
    Placeholder = 0

    If FieldRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Find failed")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim FirstAddress As String
    FirstAddress = FieldRange.Address

    Do While FieldRange.Address = FirstAddress
        FieldRange = Cells.FindNext(FieldRange)
        Placeholder = Placeholder + 1
        If Placeholder = 2000 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Loop

    FieldRange.Value = "WORKS"
End Sub
```

Maybe a solution:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub One_Find()
    Dim Placeholder As Integer
    Dim FieldRange As Range
    Dim Placeholder2 As String
    Placeholder2 = ActiveCell.Value
    Set FieldRange = Cells.Find(What:=Placeholder2, LookIn:=xlValues, _
      LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
    Placeholder = 0

    If FieldRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Find failed")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim FirstAddress As String
    FirstAddress = FieldRange.Address

    Do While FieldRange.Address = FirstAddress
        FieldRange.Value = Placeholder + "."
        FieldRange = Cells.FindNext(FieldRange)
        Placeholder = Placeholder + 1
        If Placeholder = 2000 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Loop

    FieldRange.Value = "WORKS"
End Sub
```

Placeholder2 would be the Value I would like to search for.

I'm expecting the WORKS instead of the old name but at first it was just loading for like 3 hours until I implemented the time to live as 'Placeholder'

I'm learning VBA, coming from C#.

Comment: You need to replace the value`FieldRange.Value = "WORKS"` inside the loop. Otherwise it will loop endless if it only occurs once because it will always find the same address and `FieldRange.Address = FirstAddress` is always true.

Comment: `Do While FieldRange.Address = FirstAddress` - if the value only exists once your loop will go on forever.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ but if I replace the value in the Loop I would change the thing I don't want to change

Comment: @DarthVader If you asked X but your problem is Y (see [What is the X/Y-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Please describe your actual issue and give a full example data and what you expect from your code. See [mcve].

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I now found a solution for my Problem but I would like you to look over it if you would have the time for that but thanks for your soulution it gave me an idea

Comment: @DarthVader Don't get what you mean? If you want someone to review your code (and you don't have an actual issue with the code) have a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I had a problem I now fixed

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the value `FieldRange.Value = "WORKS"` inside the loop. Otherwise it will loop endless if it only occurs once because it will always find the same address and `FieldRange.Address = FirstAddress` is always `True`.

Also the `While` should be in the end of the loop, otherwise the first find would not replace.

The following should work:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub One_Find()
    Dim FieldRange As Range
    Set FieldRange = Cells.Find(What:=ActiveCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)

    If FieldRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Find failed")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim FirstAddress As String
    FirstAddress = FieldRange.Address

    Do 
        FieldRange.Value = "WORKS"
        FieldRange = Cells.FindNext(FieldRange)
    Loop While FieldRange.Address <> FirstAddress
End Sub
```